# tmpfs with r/w access for all users anytime

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, users, tmpfs

I want to share a tmpfs folder (`/mnt/ramdisk`) between different users. All users should be able to read/write all files from that folder (just like fat32/fuse/samba) Its particularly useful for Android where every app has its own uid/gid. The solution should be on Linux/filesystem level. The problem is that most files are created 600 with own uid/gid and thus these files are inaccessible by other apps.

How can this be done?

Comment: I explicitly ask for a generic linux solution. I have selinux disabled anyway. Google did sdcard access through fuse as well on older Android versions. Maybe i can access it through generic 'mount' as well somehow.

Comment: FUSE would be ok but its usually handled by VOLD (Android VolumeManager) for sdcards. If you know how to do it with stock 'mount' command it would be a solution. Things like bindfs are not available on the system.

Comment: (del'd context: FUSE bindfs could be used to add "write by other" permission (666) to all files. Official android uses SELinux to confine apps, that might get in the way). I would hesitate to describe a system which has FUSE but you can't compile [bindfs](https://bindfs.org/) for it, as generic Linux :-P. Looks like I was completely confused about `umask`. Default ACLs as per ikkachu's answer work fine for me.  The problem case I have in mind mostly has to do with moving files into a directory, since moved files keep their permissions and they don't get modified by the directory's default ACL.

Answer (score 1):

You can (mostly) do that with default ACLs:

```
mkdir dir
setfacl -d -m u::rwx,g::rwx,o::rwx dir
chmod 0777 dir
```

The default ACL overrides the `umask` of the process creating the file, and that's what usually keeps processes from creating world-writable files. The default ACL doesn't stop processes that explicitly create files "private" files accessible only to the owner (using `open(filename, flags, 0600)` or such) or modify the permissions afterward.

`tmpfs` seems to support ACLs by default, without any mount options, assuming `CONFIG_TMPFS_POSIX_ACL` is set in the kernel configuration.

If that's not enough, you might have to setup some process to fix the permissions of the files in the directory if they are modified in ways you don't want. Use `cron` or `inotify` or such for that.

Comment: Unfortunately, it says `setfacl: ${dir}: Not supported`.

Comment: @Maniaxx, ah, apparently its a kernel configuration option: `CONFIG_TMPFS_POSIX_ACL`. Perhaps your system doesn't have that set, though I wouldn't know why.